# Getting options FROM html select TO MVC c# Controller

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, html-select, html-helper

I have no idea how to go about this, but I need to get each `<option>` from an html select multiple list, as an array, and send it back to a C# controller as such. Need to pull the text of each option for the purposes of my application.

Anybody have any idea how to go about this? I need the select so that users can choose to remove options, but once done I need to collect the options that are still in the list. Maybe via jQuery or javascript?

This is my code so far:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("NewTable", "Table", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fieldList">Field List</label>
            <select multiple class="form-control" id="fieldList" style="height: 300px">
                <option>Example 1</option>
                <option>Example 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Create Table</button>
    }
```

Comment: How do you produce the options in the first place? Surely you can just take the complement of the ones that were selected?

Comment: The options are produced by the user typing in names and hitting a button, they then appear as "options" in the select. They can then remove the ones they decide they don't want in the list anymore.

Comment: Track the selected items in hidden fields using jQuery, using the same name attribute. Then the selected ones will be posted and bound to a list property of the same name.

Comment: Can you give me more detail on how to go about this from a C# perspective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery to append to/remove from a list of hidden fields as options are added and removed, e.g.:

```
<input type="hidden" name="SelectedOptions" value="EnteredValueGoesHere" />
```

Then, create a model property to match the name:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public List<string> SelectedOptions { get; set; }
}
```

Then make sure your controller action has the following signature:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(MyModel model)
```

The default model binder binds form fields to model properties where the name of the property matches the `name` of the field so, assuming your hidden fields are correctly populated and maintained by your Javascript, this will bind the hidden fields to the list when the form is submitted.

Then, your select list becomes superficial - just used for the users' convenience, but never actually bound to a model object.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Shall I tell jquery to create a new input hidden field every time they add an option, then get the entire list of hidden inputs and their values when they hit the submit?

Comment: You just need to create/remove them as they are added/removed from the list - you don't need to do anything on submit as the hidden fields will be submitted as part of the form post. This is the canonical way to manage forms that are dynamic like this in HTML/Javascript. Then, your MVC app doesn't care how they were submitted - it just binds the form values to the list as normal, meaning no `Request.Form` nastiness or other ruining of your MVC application. Let the framework do the lifting.

Comment: Thank you. This was legendary.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("About", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
   {%>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fieldList">Field List</label>
        <select multiple class="form-control" id="fieldList" name="sl" style="height: 300px">
            <option name="op1">Example 1</option>
            <option name="op2">Example 2</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="optionValues" id="optionValues" value="1" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Create Table</button>
<%} %>
<script type="text/jscript">
    $("form").submit(function () {

        var optionsValues = "";
        $("#fieldList option").each(function () {
            optionsValues = $(this).attr("name") + "=" + $(this).attr("selected") + ",";
            alert("1");
        });
        $("#optionValues").attr("value", optionsValues);
        alert("2");
    });
</script>
```

I add hidden input field and when submitting set options value into it. At server side read value of hidden input with Request.Form("optionValues") and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign a name attribute to each option:

```
<option name="op1">Example1</option>
...
```

On server side access to options with:

```
Request.Form["op1"]
...
```

Comment: Can you give me more detail on what the controller method should do to retrieve the options?

Comment: Won't work as it will require the options to be selected - OP wants them just to be present.